# Joomla: how to store the registered user documents and pdf?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

In Joomla which plugin is used to store the particular logged user upload the document and download the document.One logged user cont see and download the other logged user.please help me urgent.I using the Joomla 3.x latest version.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation details and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, it would be better asked on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)